# return only specific fields

Tags: java, spring-boot, jdbctemplate

```
String sql = "SELECT " + columnList + " FROM result"; 

List<Result> result = jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new ResultRowMapper());
```

Result Class has so many fields . I want to return only those fields specified in the column list in my JSON whether null or not null. Solution I came up with is to create a temp class with the fields in the columnlist on the fly and then use it like below:

```
List<TempClass> result = jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new ResultRowMapper());
```

Any suggestions on how should I create this Temp class? Fields will change based on user input.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: will the `columnList` change? or its a fixed list of columns always? Also if it's going to change then you need to keep updating your `ResultRowMapper` as well. So according to me this is not a maintainable solution

Comment: Yeah. The Column list will change. Do you know of any alternative solutions?

Answer (score 1):

From your query and comment above you indicate that the column list in `SELECT` clause is dynamic which means even the `RowMapper` would change based on the list.

Let's create an interface `ResultRowMapper` which extends `org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper` as shown below:

```
public interface ResultRowMapper extends RowMapper<Person> {
    default List<String> getColumnList(){
        return Arrays.asList("id", "first_name", "last_name", "dob", "place_of_birth", "address");
    }

    default String getColumnListAsString(){
        return getColumnList().stream().collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
    }


    @Override
    default Person mapRow(ResultSet resultSet, int i) throws SQLException {
        Person p = new Person();
        p.setId(resultSet.getLong("id"));
        p.setFirstName(resultSet.getString("first_name"));
        p.setLastName(resultSet.getString("last_name"));
        p.setAddress(resultSet.getString("address"));
        p.setPlaceOfBirth(resultSet.getString("place_of_birth"));
        return p;
    }
}
```

Then I will create different implementations of this `ResultRowMapper` interface based on our needs:

```
@Component("DefaultResultRowMapper")
public class DefaultResultRowMapper implements ResultRowMapper {
}

@Component("NameResultRowMapper")
public class NameResultRowMapper implements ResultRowMapper {
    @Override
    public List<String> getColumnList(){
        return Arrays.asList("id", "first_name", "last_name");
    }


    @Override
    public Person mapRow(ResultSet resultSet, int i) throws SQLException {
        Person p = new Person();
        p.setId(resultSet.getLong("id"));
        p.setFirstName(resultSet.getString("first_name"));
        p.setLastName(resultSet.getString("last_name"));
        return p;
    }
}

@Component("AddressResultRowMapper")
public class AddressResultRowMapper implements ResultRowMapper {
    @Override
    public List<String> getColumnList(){

        return Arrays.asList("id", "dob", "place_of_birth", "address");
    }


    @Override
    public Person mapRow(ResultSet resultSet, int i) throws SQLException {
        Person p = new Person();
        p.setId(resultSet.getLong("id"));
        p.setAddress(resultSet.getString("address"));
        p.setPlaceOfBirth(resultSet.getString("place_of_birth"));
        return p;
    }
}
```

Then in the Spring boot application I will use it in the following way:

```
@Slf4j
@SpringBootApplication
public class CustomRowMapperApplication implements ApplicationRunner {

    @Autowired @Qualifier("NameResultRowMapper")
    ResultRowMapper nameResultRowMapper;

    @Autowired @Qualifier("DefaultResultRowMapper")
    ResultRowMapper defaultResultRowMapper;

    @Autowired @Qualifier("AddressResultRowMapper")
    ResultRowMapper addressResultRowMapper;

    @Autowired
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SpringApplication(CustomRowMapperApplication.class).run(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(ApplicationArguments args) throws Exception {
        List<Person> peopleWithName = jdbcTemplate.query("SELECT " + nameResultRowMapper.getColumnListAsString() 
                + " FROM person", nameResultRowMapper);
        log.info("People with name: {} ", peopleWithName);

        List<Person> people = jdbcTemplate.query("SELECT " + defaultResultRowMapper.getColumnListAsString() 
                + " FROM person", defaultResultRowMapper);
        log.info("People with all detail: {} ", people);

        List<Person> peopleWithAddress = jdbcTemplate.query("SELECT " + addressResultRowMapper.getColumnListAsString() 
                + " FROM person", addressResultRowMapper);
        log.info("People with address: {} ", peopleWithAddress);


    }
}
```